# how to insert array values in database rows?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$option_mark=array();
$option_mark[1] = $_POST['choice1_marks'];
$option_mark[2] = $_POST['choice2_marks'];
$option_mark[3] = $_POST['choice3_marks'];
$option_mark[4] = $_POST['choice4_marks'];
```

This is my array whose values i want to store in mysql inside an if loop.

```
if($result){
    foreach($choice as $option => $value){
        if($value != ""){
            if($correct_choice == $option){
                $is_correct = 1;
            }else{
                $is_correct = 0;
            }
        


            //Second Query for Choices Table
            $query = "INSERT INTO options (";
            $query .= "question_number,choice,correct,mark)";
            $query .= " VALUES (";
            $query .=  "'{$question_number}','{$value}','{$is_correct}','{$option_mark}'";
            $query .= ")";
```

this is giving me error. how can i store the values of this array in mysql in this if block.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealTime\addquestions.php on line 49

Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealTime\addquestions.php on line 49

Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealTime\addquestions.php on line 49

Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealTime\addquestions.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the full array in the `options.mark` column you could convert it to a JSON string using [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```php
$option_mark = json_encode($option_mark);
$query .= "'{$question_number}','{$value}','{$is_correct}','{$option_mark}'";
```

Then when reading from the database you would decode the JSON back to a PHP array with [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Also, make sure you're sanitizing your input to avoid MySQL injection.

Comment: Tried this. No matter what I enter its storing "0" in database in the option,mark column.